# Getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a function which prints a certain area of the DOM which is triggered by a button click which is rendered via JavaScript. See the below code...

```
function MarkQuiz() {
    var CorrectAnswers = 0,
        TotalQuestions = 0,
        CurrentQuestion = "",
        Percentage = 0,
        Output = "";

    $("select").each(function(key,value) {
        CurrentQuestion = "#" + $(value).attr("id");
        TotalQuestions = key + 1;

        if($(CurrentQuestion).val() == "Correct") {
            CorrectAnswers++;
        }
    });

    Percentage = (CorrectAnswers / TotalQuestions) * 100;

    Output = "You Scored..." +
             "<h1>"+Percentage+"%</h1>" +
             "Which means you got " + CorrectAnswers + " out of " + TotalQuestions + " correct.<br/>" +
             "<br/><a href='#' onclick='PrintCertificate('#QuizMainContent')' class='button' id='PrintCertificate'>Print your Certificate</a>";

    $("#QuizMainContent").html(Output);
}

function PrintCertificate(DOMArea) {
    var PrintArea = $(DOMArea),
    PrintWindow = window.open('','');
    PrintWindow.document.write($(PrintArea).html());
    PrintWindow.document.close();
    PrintWindow.focus();
    PrintWindow.print();
    PrintWindow.close();

}
```

However, when I click that button, I receive this error...
[image]

This is the URL to the project: http://historicalperiods.esy.es/

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: kindly share URL as it's not issue with file but with URL

Comment: Well, what code comes up when you click the handy link it gave you?

Comment: The error message says the error comes from a different file. Click the link in the console to go to that file.

Comment: `onclick='PrintCertificate('#QuizMainContent')'` quotes?

Comment: Can you provide the code from `bohQuiz.html`

Comment: @Tushar — That does appear to be a problem, but I can't see why it would give the error message quoted.

Comment: @Tushar: That's definitely **a** problem.

Comment: I have added the URL to the project to help.

Comment: <a id="PrintCertificate" class="button" #quizmaincontent')'="" onclick="PrintCertificate(" href="#">Print your Certificate</a>

found issue

got url from screenshot. lol

http://historicalperiods.esy.es/Multimedia/Product/assets/files/bohQuiz.html#

Comment: @MunjalMayank, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#" onclick="PrintCertificate(" #quizmaincontent')'="" class="button" id="PrintCertificate">Print your Certificate</a>
```

This is in your HTML. Which is what is causing the problem. As you can see, you open the attribute with `"`, then you use `"` in your javascript function, and you close the parameters in the function `'`, then you close the attribute with `'`, then you do `=""` (which doesn't make sense).

The proper way it should be:

```
<a href="#" onclick="PrintCertificate('#quizmaincontent')" class="button" id="PrintCertificate">Print your Certificate</a>
```

Comment: I am still getting this error. This is what I've done...                                                      '<br/><a href="#" onclick="PrintCertificate("#QuizMainContent")" class="button"" id="PrintCertificate">Print your Certificate</a>';

Comment: You are still opening the `onclick=""` attribute, but also using `"` for the parameter in your function. Change the double quotes (`"`) to single ones (`'`). Like this: `onclick="PrintCertificate('#QuizMainContent')"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help...

I corrected this with a little modification to the answer provided by L Ja...

```
'<br/><a href="#" onclick="PrintCertificate(\'#QuizMainContent\')" class="button" id="PrintCertificate">Print your Certificate</a>';
```

Comment: You don't **have** to escape the parameter. Since you can use `'` inbetween `"` because it sees `'` as part of the string. So: `onclick=" ' "` works. And `onclick=" " "` won't work, because the first `"` closes the attribute.